# Using Create React App without ServiceWorker

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, service-worker

Create React App by default creates a ServiceWorker.  I've deleted the files, and deleted the import and reference in `index.js`, but still get errors from Node telling me it can't compile due to the lack of `serviceWorker.js`.

How can I totally delete the ServiceWorker and still use Create React App?

Comment: Could you explain in detail. What comand did you tried to run the react-app ?

Comment: Have you also removed ```serviceWorker.unregister();``` in your index.js?